# Ghost eyes in SVG PacMan are rendered correctly in Firefox, but not in other browsers

Tags: javascript, php, svg, firefox, pacman

The GitHub repository of my SVG PacMan is available here: https://github.com/FlatAssembler/SVG-Pacman

You can see it alive here: http://flatassembler.github.io/pacman.html

The function for drawing ghosts is here:

```js
      function drawGhost(x, y, color, id, transparent) {
        //Duhovi su geometrijski likovi omedeni crtama (dno) i kubicnom Bezierovom krivuljom (vrh).
        if (/Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
          var svg = document.createElementNS(XML_namespace_of_SVG, "svg");
          svg.setAttribute("x", x - 8);
          svg.setAttribute("y", y - 16);
          var path = document.createElementNS(XML_namespace_of_SVG, "path");
          path.setAttribute("fill", color);
          var d = "M " + 0 + " " + (16 + 8);
          d +=
            "C " +
            3 +
            " " +
            0 +
            " " +
            (8 + 5) +
            " " +
            0 +
            " " +
            (8 + 8) +
            " " +
            (16 + 8);
          d += " l -4 -3 l -4 3 l -4 -3 Z";
          path.setAttribute("d", d);
          svg.setAttribute("id", id);
          if (transparent) svg.setAttribute("fill-opacity", 0.5); //Siluete (bijeli duhovi).
          svg.appendChild(path);
          var left_eye = document.createElementNS(
            XML_namespace_of_SVG,
            "circle"
          );
          left_eye.setAttribute("cx", 5);
          left_eye.setAttribute("cy", 15);
          left_eye.setAttribute("r", 2);
          left_eye.setAttribute("fill", "black");
          svg.appendChild(left_eye);
          var right_eye = document.createElementNS(
            XML_namespace_of_SVG,
            "circle"
          );
          right_eye.setAttribute("cx", 11);
          right_eye.setAttribute("cy", 15);
          right_eye.setAttribute("r", 2);
          right_eye.setAttribute("fill", "black");
          svg.appendChild(right_eye);
          zaslon.appendChild(svg);
        } else {
          var path = document.createElementNS(XML_namespace_of_SVG, "path");
          path.setAttribute("fill", color);
          var d = "M " + (x - 8) + " " + (y + 8);
          d +=
            "C " +
            (x - 5) +
            " " +
            (y - 16) +
            " " +
            (x + 5) +
            " " +
            (y - 16) +
            " " +
            (x + 8) +
            " " +
            (y + 8);
          d += " l -4 -3 l -4 3 l -4 -3 Z";
          path.setAttribute("d", d);
          path.setAttribute("id", id);
          if (transparent) path.setAttribute("fill-opacity", 0.5); //Siluete (bijeli duhovi).
          zaslon.appendChild(path);
        }
      }
```

If I enable the eyes of the ghosts to be rendered in all browsers, in browsers other than Firefox the ghosts are no longer animated. The code I use for animating the ghosts is as follows:

```js
          for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (
              jeLiPacmanPojeoDuha[i] &&
              brojacGlavnePetlje - kadaJePacmanPojeoVelikuTocku < 30
            )
              //Ako je PacMan nedavno pojeo duha, animiraj bijelu siluetu...
              zaslon
                .getElementById("bijeli" + (i + 1))
                .setAttribute(
                  "transform",
                  "translate(" +
                    (20 / 5) *
                      brojacAnimacijskePetlje *
                      xKomponentaSmjeraPacmana[smjerKretanjaSiluete[i]] +
                    " " +
                    (20 / 5) *
                      brojacAnimacijskePetlje *
                      yKomponentaSmjeraPacmana[smjerKretanjaSiluete[i]] +
                    ")"
                );
            //... inace animiraj duha.
            else
              zaslon
                .getElementById("duh" + (i + 1))
                .setAttribute(
                  "transform",
                  "translate(" +
                    (20 / 5) *
                      brojacAnimacijskePetlje *
                      xKomponentaSmjeraPacmana[smjerDuha[i]] +
                    " " +
                    (20 / 5) *
                      brojacAnimacijskePetlje *
                      yKomponentaSmjeraPacmana[smjerDuha[i]] +
                    ")"
                );
         }
```

It is as if SVG transforms, in browsers other than Firefox, have no effect on `<svg>` elements themselves. What should I do?

Comment: First, very cool project! All inside an SVG, too! Looking at the DOM, you are putting an SVG inside of another SVG, and I don't know if that is valid. Can you confirm that? In Firefox I see the nested SVGs and in Chrome I see it as flat. Can you using a group instead?

Comment: @ChrisHaas What do you mean by "using a group"? I am quite sure using SVG elements inside an SVG element is valid: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16890342/revisions

Comment: I've only ever done simple SVG work and never saw the nested syntax which I agree appears to be valid. I also missed that you were doing a literal UA test with `navigator.userAgent` and performing different logic. I saw two different DOMs but I thought the generating logic was the same. Sorry about that. For a group I mean an `<g>` element which is how SVGs group things. It is possible that nested `<svg>` elements have non-standard transform rules, but that is just me guessing. I would just make a very simple 5 element SVG and try getting the transforms working maybe?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Never heard of the `<g>` element.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Well, if I replace the inner `<svg>` with `<g>`, the ghosts jump into the top-left part of `zaslon`.

Comment: I downloaded your project and re-enabled the eyes for all browsers. When I then run the code through Chrome, your transforms all appear to be working, they are just jumpy. Unfortunately between the logic and language (Croatian?) it is very hard to debug. You've seriously made a very awesome thing, it is just beyond my ability to debug further. My one and only last guess is that it appears that you are adding and removing DOM items, is that right? If so, it is possible that Chrome is performing an optimization that you don't want, and I have no specific idea what it would be either.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Well, yes, I am adding and removing DOM elements. And why do you think the animation becomes jumpy in Chrome when I add the eyes, but is not jumpy if I do not add the eyes?

Comment: My wild guess is that Chrome is handling a nested `<svg>` in a special way, but I seriously have no idea why. I'm basing this solely on that's the only difference that I can see in your code. You should be able to make a very, very simple test for this, just a simple `<svg>` with a nested `<svg>` and try animating that at the same framerate as your current loop. Don't use any of your existing code for this test, make this code independent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230344/discussion-between-flatassembler-and-chris-haas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself, here is how I modified the `drawGhost` function:

```js
        function drawGhost(x, y, color, id, transparent) {
            //Duhovi su geometrijski likovi omedeni crtama (dno) i kubicnom Bezierovom krivuljom (vrh).
            var svg = document.createElementNS(XML_namespace_of_SVG, "g");
            svg.setAttribute("x", x - 8);
            svg.setAttribute("y", y - 16);
            var path = document.createElementNS(XML_namespace_of_SVG, "path");
            path.setAttribute("fill", color);
            var d = "M " + (x - 8) + " " + (y + 8);
            d +=
                    "C " +
                    (x - 5) +
                    " " +
                    (y - 16) +
                    " " +
                    (x + 5) +
                    " " +
                    (y - 16) +
                    " " +
                    (x + 8) +
                    " " +
                    (y + 8);
            d += " l -4 -3 l -4 3 l -4 -3 Z";
            path.setAttribute("d", d);
            svg.setAttribute("id", id);
            if (transparent)
                svg.setAttribute("fill-opacity", 0.5); //Siluete (bijeli duhovi).
            svg.appendChild(path);
            var left_eye = document.createElementNS(
                    XML_namespace_of_SVG,
                    "circle"
                    );
            left_eye.setAttribute("cx", x - 8 + 5);
            left_eye.setAttribute("cy", y - 16 + 15);
            left_eye.setAttribute("r", 2);
            left_eye.setAttribute("fill", "black");
            svg.appendChild(left_eye);
            var right_eye = document.createElementNS(
                    XML_namespace_of_SVG,
                    "circle"
                    );
            right_eye.setAttribute("cx", x - 8 + 11);
            right_eye.setAttribute("cy", y - 16 + 15);
            right_eye.setAttribute("r", 2);
            right_eye.setAttribute("fill", "black");
            svg.appendChild(right_eye);
            zaslon.appendChild(svg);
        }
```